# RxJS await ajax respose before processing next buffered chunk

Tags: javascript, ajax, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm using RxJS with a basic Subject object, which receives inputs from various places at unknown times. These inputs need to be stacked up and sent to the server asynchronously - but I need to wait until that ajax request completes before attempting to process the next buffered set of inputs.

flatMapLatest is not suitable in my case as each response has to be handled uniquely.

I could pause the buffer while the ajax request is in process, but that means I would lose inputs, which is unacceptable.

I see the buffer opening object is just an observable, could I somehow combine both a timer observable and a custom observable which I fire when my ajax request completes and when the ajax request is sent I could suspend the timer one?

Sorry I don't have any code to show yet, I'm still at the design stage really.

Is what I want to do feasible or am I going about it incorrectly?

**EDIT**

This is the code I have so far, and it appears to do what I want - but am still open to improvements.

```
var bufferedIntervalPauser = new Rx.Subject<boolean>();
var pausableInterval = Rx.Observable.interval(500).pausable(bufferedIntervalPauser);
var purStream = this.updateReqestSubject.asObservable()
    .buffer(pausableInterval)
    .where(b => (b || []).length > 0)

var purSub = purStream.subscribe(
    next => {
        bufferedIntervalPauser.onNext(false); // pause the buffer window

        SomeAjaxMethod(next, {
            success: res => {
                this.HandleResult(res);
            },
            always: () => {
                // when the ajax completes, resume the buffer
                bufferedIntervalPauser.onNext(true);
            }
        });
    },
    err => {
        console.error(err);
    });

// start
bufferedIntervalPauser.onNext(true);
```

Comment: Rx has a behavioural contract in which it will only run one handler at a time for each incoming value and only one value at a time. If extra values come in they are automatically buffered. You simply don't (or shouldn't) get any overlaps. If you are working with a component that breaks the contract then you can add the `.Synchronize()` operator (at least in C# you can) to make the observable comply with the contract.

Comment: I have updated my answer, to show how to use `Concat`. This works fine in C#/.NET, but YMMV in RxJava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use just the `buffer` operator. As @Enigmativity points out, Rx has a serialized protocol, so your handler wont ever run concurrently i.e. it wont be called while it is still running from a previous call. If however your handler itself calls a non-blocking/asnyc method, then there would be nothing blocking Rx to call your handler before some async response is created. In this case you may want to wrap your async call in an observable sequence. Then you can use an operator like `concat`, to ensure serialization of multiple observable sequences

EDIT:
Your issue here is that you are doing async work in your subscription. What you need to do is treat your `SomeAjaxMethod` as an observable sequence and then just use composition.

```
//Psuedo code as I dont have a Java IDE at hand
this.updateReqestSubject.asObservable()
   .Buffer(500ms)
   .Select(buffer=>SomeAjaxMethod(buffer).asObservable().Catch(/*Swallow to match example*/))
   .Concat() //Concatenate the IObservable<IObservable<>> into IObservable<>
   .Subscribe(
     res=>this.HandleResult(res),
     err => {
       console.error(err);
     });
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question and added the code I'm using - if you get a chance can you explain how `concat` could achieve the same thing please?

Comment: @Marlon - Can you please show enough code for us to see why this is needed? The Rx contract shouldn't require it at all.